# Is it possible to incorporate $DisplayPieces: 2, into a slider demo that doesn't already have it?

Tags: javascript, slider, jssor

I'm modifying this theme here
http://www.jssor.com/testcase/full-screen-slider-new-api.source.html
I'm trying to add the $DisplayPieces: 2, but it seems to break :/
Is it at all POSSIBLE to incorporate features from other demos into this one?
Any advice would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

To display more than 1 slide in slides container, you'd manually set $SlideWidth to fit slides container.

In the demo mentioned above, the width of slides container is 600px, please set $SlideWidth to 300 then.

```
var options = {
    $SlideWidth: 300,
    $DisplayPieces: 2,
    $SlideDuration: 800,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
    $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
    $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
    $AutoPlayInterval: 1500                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
};
```

Comment: lol! I JUST got it woking on my own and then came here to delete the question. Talk about close timing ;) I'm going to leave this up tho as I'm hoping it will help someone else looking to customize jssor. Thanks for replying so fast! Cheers!